# Como usar uma data dinâmica pra agendar uma tarefa com @Scheduled do Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

Bom dia, tenho uma aplicação onde o pessoal do RH seta um determinado dia do mês para que os lançamentos do sistema sejam encerrados, ou seja, depois desse dia ninguém mais poderá fazer lançamentos. Então, preciso que o sistema faça esse bloqueio no dia especificado.

Andei pesquisando @Scheduled do Spring e vi quem tem um atributo **cron** que poderia ser usado, entretanto, não achei uma forma de usar no **cron**, a data que o pessoal do RH vai inserir.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
public void fecharLancamentos() {
    //codigo a ser executado
}
```

Existe uma forma de usar essa data dinamicamente no @Scheduled? Algo do tipo:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * {meuObjeto.getMinhaData} * *")
    public void fecharLancamentos() {
        //codigo a ser executado
    }
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Esse valor é definido quando a aplicação sobe e não pode ser modificado, deve ser uma constante.

Uma possível solução seria dentro do seu método anotado com `@Scheduled` você ler de um banco de dados ou algo similar o valor que o RH decidiu. Então se for a hora certa, você executa.

Por exemplo, todo dia às 00:00h você lê o valor, e então cria um `ScheduledExecutorService` agendado para a hora salva no seu banco de dados/memória. Nesse caso a mudança só faz diferença na virada do dia, você pode  regular seu `@Scheduled` para rodar a cada minuto ou como preferir, mas terá de controlar a execução como for melhor para o seu propósito.

edit:
Caso esse valor só precise ser setado uma vez você pode usar uma variável de ambiente ou de um arquivo de configuração como um .properties da sua aplicação. Nesse caso ficaria `@Scheduled(cron = "${variavel}")`